# df IndexError only with with parameter query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm experiencing an interesting error. If my query uses a fixed value for the criteria that is returned to a PANDAS data frame, I can successfully reference the returned data. However, I'm expanding the function to receive a variable that would be used in the query. When I revise the command to a parameter query, I get the error:

`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

Here is my query with parameter. Note - There should always only be one row of data returned.

Any thoughts?

```
def getMapData(unique_id):
    if unique_id is None:
       unique_id = "abc123" #set default value
    loc_query = pd.read_sql_query('''
                                  SELECT LAT, LON, [firstname] + ' ' + [lastname] AS full_name FROM PROPERTY
                                  WHERE ((unique_id)=(?))''', connection, params=(unique_id,))
    #Convert SQL to DF:
    loc_df = pd.DataFrame(loc_query, columns = ['LAT', 'LON', 'full_name'])
    return(loc_df['LAT'].iloc[0], loc_df['LON'].iloc[0], loc_df['full_name'].iloc[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. This was sort of a logical error. My default unique ID was invalid. There were zero records returned, which tripped the error at iloc[0]. I added a condition to see if dataframe is empty before returning value.

`if loc_df.empty == False:`